# Facebook Accountkit integration with Vue.js 2.0

Tags: facebook, vue.js

When i load the project everything works fine. But when i do a browser refresh in App.vue it gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: AccountKit.init is not a function(…)

Any idea why?

My `index.html` file:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
      <!-- meta tags -->
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="description" content=""/>
      <meta name="generator" content="2014.1.1.276"/>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=IE8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- meta tags end-->

      <!-- facebook opengraph meta -->
      <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
      <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://"/>
      <meta property="og:description" content=" "/>
      <meta property="og:image" content="image address"/> <!-- facebook opengraph meta ends-->

      <title>Sheba.xyz</title>

      <!-- Stylesheets -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i"
            rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Scripts -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">

      <app></app>

    </div>
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And App.vue is

```
<script>
  /* eslint-disable */
  import $ from 'jquery'
  import {appId, appState, appVersion} from './env'
  import navigation from './components/header'
  import mainFooter from './components/footer'

  export default{
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      navigation, mainFooter
    },
    created: function () {
      AccountKit.init({
        appId: appId,
        state: appState,
        version: appVersion
      })
    }
  }
  /* eslint-enable */
</script>

<template>
  <div id="">

    <navigation></navigation>

    <router-view></router-view>

    <main-footer></main-footer>

  </div>
</template>
<style>
  @import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
  @import "./assets/css/style.css";
</style>
```

Comment: Are you putting AccountKit_OnInteractive outside `export default`? That way, it won't be available in another file.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 putting it inside export default gives error in webstorm.

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make `Acc` available in another file, we must include it in what's `export`ed. But we can't just put `import ...` inside `export default {...}`: `export default {...}` is a shorthand for `var exported = {...};` + `export default exported;`, which means what's inside `{}` obeys js's object literal syntax: `{key1: val1, key2: val2 ...}` (or we can use the shorthand `{foo}` for `{foo: foo}` in ES6). So to export `Acc`, we can write:

```
var Acc = function() {...};
export default {
    // ...
    Acc: Acc
    // ...
};
```

But wait, there's another problem: in another file (like `index.js`), we don't directly use what we exported in this .vue file, instead, we use a "component", which is generated after vue compile `App.vue` for us. Which means, `Acc` may not be in the component object we use in another file. So we need to follow vue's convention here: if we want `Acc` to be a function of component `App`, we put it in the `methods` property of our source object. Like this:

```
export default{

    name: 'app',

    components: {
        navigation
    },

    methods: {
        Acc: function() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And use `App.Acc()` in another file.

Comment: @ArnabRahman Don't see where you import AccountKit in the code

Comment: I've added the facebook sdk script in index.html. This code works first time but browser refresh gives the error.

Comment: @ArnabRahman maybe the `created` is called before the account script is loaded. Try export the method and wrap it in [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)?

Comment: I've initialized accountkit inside domContentLoaded event but still no luck gives same error after page reload.

Comment: @ArnabRahman `log` AccountKit in the console to see what's different before and after refresh?

Comment: script stops running after that error. Do you know how to import script from cdn in webpack?

Comment: @ArnabRahman wait, there's no "init" in https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js ?

Comment: I know when you load the sdk it loads another script from inside "https:\/\/sdk.accountkit.com\/en_US\/sdk.js?hash=65dc84a281364fad08c2a5ab7e9e2d0e" this has init in it.

Comment: It feels like i'm the only one implementing facebook account kit in vue.js :/